# Convert CellSet into DataTable

Tags: datatable, mdx

As a part of one of my project, I need to convert cellset into a datatable. It would be excellent if the caller of this method could specify which dimensions are needed as columns and which of them are needed for rows, also the same for measures. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed to execute MDX queries in my project which heavily relies on ADO Datasets and datatables. Actually the requirement was to be able to see more or less what i see in SSMS when a MDX query is executed.

For example, when this mdx is executed in AdventureWorks database

```
select
{[Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Country].&[France]} on columns,
[Product].[Category].[All Products] on Rows
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

the result set we get is:

```
               |     France
=====================================
All Products   |    $4,607,537.94
```

For this result, a datatable with two columns is created containing a single datarow. The "France" value in the second column is its caption, not the column name.

I used this function to convert a cellset into a datatable. Not supplied function GetColumnName(num) returns a name for a column based on passed num integer value.

```
Function Cellset2Datatable(ByVal cs As CellSet) As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dc As DataColumn
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim i, j As Integer

        Dim num As Integer = 0
        Dim nNumberOfGroupingColumns As Integer = 0


        If cs.Axes.Count > 1 Then
            For Each m As Member In cs.Axes(1).Positions(0).Members
                num += 1
                dc = New DataColumn
                dc.ColumnName = GetColumnName(num)
                dt.Columns.Add(dc)
                nNumberOfGroupingColumns += 1
            Next
        End If



        Dim sCaption As String

        For Each p As Position In cs.Axes(0).Positions
            sCaption = ""
            For Each m As Member In p.Members
                If sCaption.Equals("") Then
                    sCaption = String.Format("[{0}]", m.Caption.Trim)
                Else
                    sCaption = String.Format("{0} / [{1}]", sCaption, m.Caption.Trim)
                End If
            Next

            num += 1
            dc = New DataColumn
            dc.ColumnName = GetColumnName(num)
            dc.Caption = sCaption
            dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        Next


        'import data

        Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
        Dim py As Position

        If nNumberOfGroupingColumns > 0 Then

            For y = 0 To cs.Axes(1).Positions.Count - 1
                py = cs.Axes(1).Positions(y)
                i = 0

                dr = dt.NewRow

                For Each m As Member In py.Members
                    dr.Item(i) = m.Caption
                    i += 1
                Next

                For x = 0 To cs.Axes(0).Positions.Count - 1
                    dr.Item(i) = cs(x, y).Value
                    i += 1
                Next

                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Next

        Else

            dr = dt.NewRow

            For i = 0 To cs.Axes(0).Positions.Count - 1
                dr.Item(i) = cs(i).Value
            Next

            dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        End If

        Return dt

    End Function
```

At first, columns are added. A check is done to see if any "grouping" columns exist in vertical axis exist and in this case the corresponding columns are added:

```
    If cs.Axes.Count > 1 Then
        For Each m As Member In cs.Axes(1).Positions(0).Members
            num += 1
            dc = New DataColumn
            dc.ColumnName = GetColumnName(num)
            dt.Columns.Add(dc)
            nNumberOfGroupingColumns += 1
        Next
    End If
```

The next step is to add the columns that correspond to the horizontal axis

```
    For Each p As Position In cs.Axes(0).Positions
        sCaption = ""
        For Each m As Member In p.Members
            If sCaption.Equals("") Then
                sCaption = String.Format("[{0}]", m.Caption.Trim)
            Else
                sCaption = String.Format("{0} / [{1}]", sCaption, m.Caption.Trim)
            End If
        Next

        num += 1
        dc = New DataColumn
        dc.ColumnName = GetColumnName(num)
        dc.Caption = sCaption
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
    Next
```

The column's caption in this step is used to store all level values. For example
[Accessories].[France].[Internet Order Count] becomes [Accessories] / [France] / [Internet Order Count].
The final step is to import data into the datatable. Both cases are handled here: whether "grouping" columns exist or not.

The function does not handle the case that more than two axes exist.

My experience on Analysis services and MDX is limited, I just studied what I needed for the project requirements so I apologize for my "simplistic" description on regarding concepts.

Comment: Simply dumping code without explanation encourages copying and pasting and may result in a lack of true understanding for the OP.  Recommend you append this post with some explanation for each part of the code.  Bear in mind that the OP may be a beginner and so code dumping may prove to be overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

If in your project use [XMLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLA) you can choose between 2 formats: **Multidimensional Dataset** or **Tabular Rowset**.

- Multidimensional Dataset:

  This format will give you a cellset (you already know it).
- Tabular Rowset:

  This one should be easier to convert into datatable.